# Strict inequality in lower semicontinuity of BV functions

Tags: analysis, bounded-variation

Does anybody know an example of a sequence $f_k \in  BV(\mathbb{R^n}) \ $ where $n>1$ and $f \in L^{1}_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb{R^n})$ such that $ f_k \rightarrow f \ $ in $L^{1}_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb{R^n}) \ $  but we have strictly:
$ \|Df\|(\mathbb{R^n}) < \liminf \|Df_k\|(\mathbb{R^n})  \ $?

Thanks a lot for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$f_k(x)=k^{-1}\sin (kx_1) \phi(x) $$ 
where $\phi$ is smooth, nonnegative and compactly supported. Then $f_k\to 0$ in $L^1$, but the integrals of $|Df_k|$ are bounded from below: 
$$\int |\cos (kx_1)|\phi(x) \ge \int \cos^2 (kx_1)\phi(x)=\frac12\int \phi(x)+\frac12 \int \cos (2kx_1)\phi(x) $$ 
where 
$$\int \cos (2kx_1)\phi(x)  = - \frac{1}{2k} \int \sin (2kx_1)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_1} \to 0 $$
(or just use  the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma).